# This video has been removed by the user - add a redirect link

Tags: youtube

I deleted a video with the intent of replacing it with a newer version. Now, preexisting links are broken. Is there a way to redirect? Alternatively, is there a way to have a link to the new video, instead of just displaying this:

> This video has been removed by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no possible way of redirecting a removed video. Once it's deleted, there's nothing we can do.

However if you haven't deleted the video, you could create a "replacing video" and create an annotation on the old one, letting people know that there's a new version of that video, like the example on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XK-oTUtFj4